# When is C++ destructor called on an object in heap?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, memory-leaks

Suppose a class and its usage

```
#include <vector>
class B
{
 public:
     B() {temp = 0;}; // implemented 
    ~B() {} ; // implmented 
 private : 
      int temp; 
      // it holds a std::bitset , a std::vector.. It is quite large in size.
};

class A 
{
    private:
    std::vector<B*> * _data ; 
    public: 
    A()
    {
       _data = new std::vector<B*>(0); 
    }
    ~A()
     {
         for(unsigned int idx_ = 0; idx_ < _data->size(); ++idx_)
              delete _data->at(idx_);
         delete _data ; 
     }
     void addB()
     {
          B * temp = new B();
          _data->push_back(temp);
     }
}



int main()
{
   A temp; 
   temp.addB(); 
    // Do something 
}
```

My question is does this code leak memory ? Also suppose another usage

```
int main()
{
     A * temp = new A(); 
     temp->addB(); 

     delete temp ; // 1 
}
```

Is 1 here required ? If I have a pointer to the heap and the pointer goes out of scope is the destructor called on the element in heap. I just want to be sure about this point. 
Thank you !

Comment: I see at least 4 separate errors in this code, even aside from the ridiculous overuse of `new`.

Comment: @T.C. Could you give me a pointer as to what they are ?

Comment: @T.C. used compiler. Corrected stupidity.

Comment: @T.C. You said over usage of new. For the actual program B is quite large is size . And I need >million B's in A . If I do not use a pointer to B , but B itself, won't std::vector be forced to use contiguous memory in heap to store ? And so wont the number of elements it can hold be reduced ? If I use pointers can't B be stored non contiguously ? Is this reasoning wrong ?

Comment: @nnrales If you use one pointer to allocate an array, it's contiguous too. You can have an array (pointer or vector) of single pointers (each one to one data thing). That way, only the pointer array is contiguous.

Comment: @nnrales if `B` only contains an `int`, then `vector<B*>` will use at least as much  contiguous memory as `vector<B>`.  A way to avoid large contiguous chunks is to use `deque` which is like a list of medium-size chunks

Comment: @M.M I debated this too. Wont the iteration speed decrease when I use a deque as the memory is not contiguous ? B is much larger than an int.

Comment: @nnrales try it and see. But you were talking about using millions of separate blocks, surely iteration speed there is slower than using thousands of blocks. If `B` is larger than `int` you should update your question to show the true size of `B`

Comment: @M.M Talking with you made me unsure of the decision I made. The way I was thinking is , since the std::vector of pointers are contiguous , I will be able to loop over them quickly and then follow the pointer to the actual object. I guess the cost of this , and moving from one node of deque to another is same. I have much left to learn.

Comment: accessing by index would require more operations in the deque... there's no simple blanket answers for large datasets though. cpu and memory caching come into play, OS allocation strategies etc.

Comment: What is `sizeof(B)` in your real code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it easier to associate when a destructor will be called and when it wont be, use this rule of thumb: When the memory for an object is being reclaimed, then the object's destructor is called (and the memory is reclaimed right after that).

Your first example does not leak any memory.
Here is why... You essentially created 2 objects.

A and B.

A was on the stack. The memory for object A was created **implicitly** on the stack.

B was created on the heap **explicitly** by your code.

When main() returned every Object on the stack is destroyed. i.e the memory that was being used to hold the members of the object on the stack (in this case object A) is being reclaimed implicitly. Since the object (A) is actually being destroyed and its memory being reclaimed, the destructor for A gets called.

Within A's destructor you are explicitly telling the runtime to reclaim all the memory what was explicitly allocated by your code (i.e when you call delete). Thus the memory for object B is being reclaimed too.

Thus there was no leak.

In the 2nd example, you again create 2 objects A and B.
Here, the memory for both objects resides in the heap. This was allocated explicitly by your code using the new operator.
In this case, your code never reclaims the memory allocated for A. i.e **delete** is never called for A.

The stack for main() only contains the memory for a pointer to A. The main() stack itself does not contain the memory for A. So when main() returns, all that is being destroyed is the memory that was allocated for the **pointer to A**, and not A itself.
Since the memory for A was never reclaimed, it was never "destroyed". Thus its destructor was never called and correspondingly "B" was never destroyed either.

Comment: thank you for helping me understand this better. Sorry for the poor code and over use of new. I did not know that elements in std::vector are by default allocated on the heap

Comment: I never said that the _data is being implictly allocated on the heap.

Comment: There is a possible misinterpretation here. Think about what happens if you don't call "delete _data" in A's destructor. Do you have a leak even if A's destructor was called? Also consider what happens if you define the class a little differently .. instead of "std::vector<B*> * _data ; ", use "std::vector<B*> _data ;" i.e _data is not a pointer to a vector, but the vector itself. Would you call (or is it even possible to call) delete _data in this case..? Why and why not?

Answer (score 2):

No, destructor is not implicitly called.  you have to delete temp, at which time it's destructor is called.  It could be argued that since it's main that's returning in your example, the process is going to exit and memory will be reclaimed by OS, but in general, each new needs a delete.

Comment: implicit reclamation of heap memory is called Garbage Collection, which is what Java does.

Comment: @ thanks. Also about the first part. Is there any subtle memory leakage that is occurring ?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'll have to leave that to you.  Essentially, every new needs a corresponding delete.

Comment: @nnrales Yes. You're not following the rule of 3 or 5 or 0. What happens if you do `A a, b; a = b;`?

Comment: @zenith I ignored the copy cons and copy assignment operator for readability. I do follow the rule of 3 , trying to learn how to use move semantics too.

Comment: @nnrales Your time might be better spent learning not to use dynamic allocation so much.

Comment: @juanchopanza Is it because I don't know how to use it , or is there a reason why you say that ?

Comment: @nnrales Using new and delete for something eg. a vector could do, introduces new possibilities to make (hard-to-find) errors in the code. The most obvious one is to forget delete (-> memory congestion and no destructor calling), but there are others too. While raw pointers can do more things (and some things differerently) than the container classes, often there's simply no reason to not use the bug-free classes.

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb is if you've used `new` to create something then you have to use `delete` to destroy it. Pointers are all about manual memory management (they are heritage from the C language) or, as Scott Meyers once called them, "running with scissors". References are a C++ thing (or you can also check out smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr`).

**UPDATE**
I thought it would be useful to show an example with `std::shared_ptr`. It has *dumb* pointer semantics, but its destructor -since it actually has one- calls pointed object's destructor.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;


struct Simple {
    std::string txt;
    Simple(const std::string& str) : txt(str) {}
    Simple(){}
    ~Simple() { cout << "Destroyed " << txt << endl; }
};


template<class U> using SPtr = shared_ptr<U>;
template<class V> using PtrToSimple = typename conditional<is_same<SPtr<Simple>, V>::value,SPtr<Simple>,Simple*>::type;


template<class T>
void modify(PtrToSimple<T> pt) {

    pt->txt.append("_modified");
    // equivalent to (*pt).txt.append("_modified");
}


int main() {

    auto shared = shared_ptr<Simple>(new Simple("shared_ptr_obj"));
    modify<decltype(shared)>(shared);
    cout << shared->txt << endl;

    auto dumb = new Simple("dumb_ptr_obj");
    modify<decltype(dumb)>(dumb);
    cout << dumb->txt << endl;

    // The object pointed by 'shared'
    // will be automatically deleted.
    // dumb's object won't
    return 0;
}
```

prints

> shared_ptr_obj_modified
>
> dumb_ptr_obj_modified
>
> Destroyed shared_ptr_obj_modified